# Forum Available on Tapatalk Android App

Tags: support

The mobile app [Tapatalk](http://www.tapatalk.com/faq.php) is very convenient for mobile access to forums. I couldn't find this site on Tapatalk, but perhaps I'm using the wrong search criterion. Has anyone successfully accessed Stack Exchange sites via Tapatalk? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackExchange now appears to have its own Android app:

[StackExchange App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)

Answer (score 5):

This was asked on the [main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72258/stack-overflow-on-tapatalk) a while ago. As the answers there mention, Tapatalk lists on their homepage that they support:

> Currently phpBB3 3.x, vBulletin 3.6 to 4.x, xenForo, IPBoard 3.x, SMF 1.1.11+/2.x, MyBB 1.4/1.6, bbPress 1.1/2.0 and Kunena 1.6+ are supported. Other forum system might also support Tapatalk with plugins developed by third party developers using Tapatalk API.

Stack Exchange isn't any of the things listed, and hasn't manually added support with the API they mention, so we're not going to show up in that list. However, there are several Android apps [specifically for Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android), including [Droidstack](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-now-with-chat-support), [StackAnywhere](https://stackapps.com/questions/2370/stackanywhere-a-stack-exchange-client-for-android), and [Stacks](https://stackapps.com/questions/2365/stacks-for-android)